# Enable PHP DOM extension on centOS 5.5 without recompiling

Tags: php5, centos5

I'm trying to install the Google Data PHP Library, and the install checker is telling me that DOM isn't installed. After some googling it appeared that I needed to install php-xml, but that was already installed. I then decided to reinstall php-xml, but after uninstalling it, it appears that it has disappeared from the standard repo's entirely.

My PHP was apparently configured with the following

```
'./configure' '--build=i686-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=i686-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-png' '--with-pspell' '--with-expat-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-track-vars' '--enable-trans-sid' '--enable-yp' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-memory-limit' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dbx' '--enable-dio' '--with-mime-magic=/usr/share/file/magic.mime' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--without-odbc' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter'
```

How can I enable DOM without compiling PHP? (I'm using the standard repo one at the moment).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On CentOS you should be able to just run `yum install php-dom` or `yum install php-xml`.  That will install php-xml and any dependencies (such as libxslt) and give you support for dom.

In older versions of CentOS such as 4 you had to use the `--enablerepo=centosplus` but this is not required in 5.

Comment: I have tried to do your solution but unfortunately package not available. I am using CentOS 5.5 my php version is 5.3

Comment: Old post. But, thought it might be good to note here, `'--disable-dom'` still shows in `php_info()` after running `yum install php-xml`. But, it **does** work.

Comment: newest php-xml seems to be 5.3.3 in CentOS 6 now.